# CHTML changes in .razor file not displaying is browser

Tags: html, razor

I have made some changes in chtml code of .razor file bt when I save changes and refresh the browser page they are not displaying. Please help

Comment: please share your code

Comment: For instance, i wanted to remove the following div

<h3>EXPEREINCE</h3>
but even after removing and saving my code it still is displaying in preview.